# Sass is installed, but command cannot be found

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have a Cpanel-based hosting plan with my provider.  I've managed to install both Compass and Sass by using Putty and everything seems to be fine, however when I try to use it I get `sass: command not found` from the terminal.

I understand that this is probably due to the fact that Sass/Compass are not referred to in environment variables but so far have been unable to find a way to get this to work.  I don't have sudo access to the server and have read that I can (maybe) add the PATH manually but I'm not having much luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you have Ruby & [RubyGems installed](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3):
2. Make sure your GEM_HOME's bin directory is on your path:

   ```
   $ echo $PATH | grep $GEM_HOME
   ```

   2.1. If it isn't, then:

   ```
   $ echo "export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin" >> "~/.bash_profile"
   ```
3. Install the sass RubyGem package

   ```
   gem install sass
   ```

Comment: Can you explain to me what this does?  It's not going to break anything, is it?

Comment: When i type the first command I get this 
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

Comment: Also, when I type the second command I get the following "-jailshell: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory" even though typing in dir at the command prompt does show a .bash_profile file??

Comment: Answer updated! In the case that the append command fails. You may have to add the line `export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin"` to the bottom of your **.bash_profile** file manually (`$ nano .bash_profile`).

Comment: I've just added the line manually to the bottom of .bash_profile, but nothing seems to have changed.  Typing in sass -v still tells me the command is not found.  I've installed it as instructed, too.

Comment: Also, if I type echo $GEM_HOME nothing is returned.  Confused.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out @MatRichardson. If you could kindly explain the steps to how you created $GEM_HOME it would be most appreciated.