# Can't install Sass on OS X

Tags: sass, failed-installation

I'm trying to install Sass on my OS X 10.8.4 machine.

When I enter "sudo gem install sass" I get the following output:

```
Successfully installed sass-3.2.9
1 gem installed
```

But afterwards, when I enter "sass -v", I get:

```
-bash: sass: command not found
```

My path file is like the following:

```
#homebrew should always take presedence
/usr/local/bin

#the default stack
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

I also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122268/installing-and-using-sass) which unfortunately didn't help. It added the following line to my .bash_profile.

```
export PATH=#homebrew should always take presedence:/usr/local/bin:#the default stack:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
```

Any thoughts...

Comment: That *exact* line? Remove the comments and it should work.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for the insight. Could you please post the uncommented version as well because I removed the comments from the path file and re-added the line into the .bash_profile but it keeps adding with the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your comments are breaking the `PATH`. Just do this instead:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: thanks but that didn't help unfortunately... any other thoughts?